# Merge two tables in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update

im fairly new with mysql, but i got two tables i want to merge together.

users2 rows: 
`` `id`, `gulaged`, `wbeg`, `wcash`, `wad`, `wfurry`, `wmute`, `wtoxic`, `dbump`, `message`, `banreason`, `steam_id`, `value`, `bg`, `eggs` ``

users3 rows:
`` `id`, `steam_id`, `value` ``

ive tried multiple things like

```
INSERT INTO users2(`id`, `steam_id`, `value`) SELECT `id`, `steam_id`, `value` from users3 WHERE `id` = `id`
```

and

```
update users2
INNER JOIN users3 on users2.id = users3.id
set users2.steam_id = users3.steam_id and users2.value = users3.value
```

all i want is to import users3 rows where the id is the same as users2.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results. It is unclear whether you want an `UPDATE` or an `INSERT` query (or maybe both).

Comment: i want to update value & steam_id in users2 from users3 where id is the same in users 2 and users3

Answer (score 1):

From the comments:

> I want to update `value` and `steam_id` in `users2` from `users3` where `id` is the same in `users 2` and `users3`.

Consider the `update ... join ...` syntax:

```
update users2 u2
inner join users3 u3 on u3.id = u2.id
set u2.value = u3.value, u2.steam_id = u3.steam_id
```